# Wordpress File handle - fopen, fwrite not working with $.ajax or $.post Jquery

Tags: php, ajax

I am making some log for all the action done in the site that can be store in a .txt file.

my php code in working fine when doing a normal load, but when i use ajax it seems like i doesn't read the fopen, fpost method on php..

please check my code.

This is my function and ajax handler

```
function action_log( $msg ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $path = "wp-content/themes/creation/templates/inc/log.txt";
    $myfile = (file_exists($path)) ? fopen($path, "a+") : fopen($path, "w+");
    $txt = $msg.$current_user->display_name."\n";

    if ( $myfile ) {
        fwrite( $myfile, $txt );
        fclose( $myfile );
        chmod($path, 0777);
        $result = $txt;
        return $result;
    } else {
        $result = $myfile;
        return $txt;
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_action-log-ajax', 'action_log_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_action-log-ajax', 'action_log_ajax');
function action_log_ajax(){

    $post = $_REQUEST;
    $msg = $post['msg'];
    $write = action_log( $msg );

    exit( wp_send_json_success( $write ) );
}
```

My jquery plugin function

```
  $.send_log_changes = function( $msg ) {

    var msgs = $msg;
    var action = 'action-log-ajax';
    console.log(msgs);

    $.post({
      url: plugins_ajax.ajaxUrl,
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        action: action,
        msg: msgs
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function( respones ) {
        console.log(respones);
      }

    });
 }
```

I tried using .ajax, .get, .post and still the same error.
it always return in `False`and cant write/open in the file.

Comment: Can you check the code here: `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_action-log-ajax', 'action_log_ajax');`, I believe it's should be `wp_ajax_nopriv_action_log_ajax`

Comment: @TungDu - hey bud, thanks for the answer, but the `action-log-ajax` is having no problem about the code. it is only a call, and the ajax is working and returning value, but it returns a `false` value, that cant read the `fopen()` and `fwrite()`

Comment: sorry, a bit misreading. For file handling in WP, I think you should use WP FileSystem. Tut here, it may help: http://ottopress.com/2011/tutorial-using-the-wp_filesystem/

Comment: you should never write anything to the theme directory. It will most likely be write protected or you will cuase huge mess on a network install.

Comment: okay, thanks for the tip. i will transfer the log when its fully done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the issue with this line:

```
$path = "wp-content/themes/creation/templates/inc/log.txt";
```

You need to use the full path, not a relative part, while using `fopen()` or `file_exists()`.

Something like this should fix your issue:

```
$path = get_template_directory() . "/templates/inc/log.txt";
```

[`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) will return the absolute server path, without a trailing slash.

Comment: `get_template_directory()` will return the absolute path of the parent theme. so i used `get_stylesheet_directory()` and it seems like the problem is all about the path.. great help (y).

Comment: Either way, I was trying to use get_template_directory_uri() and that was wrong ;) Thanks for this!